# Web components for card elements

Tags: polymer

Are there any web components for the designs shown here. 
https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-actions

Comment: Man don't down vote simply without reason. I have done enough research on webcomponents.org. My question is specific to the designs mentioned in that page.

Answer (score 2):

Well... there is [paper-card](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-card). The demo includes several examples that can fit with the designs you are looking for.

Comment: yeah I'm using paper-card as of now.